# How to navigate among the views in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am new in mvc. due to lack of knowledge i am not being able to do one thing.suppose i have view Index.cshtml and this view reside in home folder. i have register folder in home folder and in register folder there is view called register.cshtml. i have another folder called catalog in home folder. when i will run my application then by default Index view will render and there will be two button or two link button. one is button text is Catalog and another button text is register.

when user click on register button then register view should load and when user click on Catalog button then Catalog view should load. how could i do this ? what kind of code i need to write and what kind of code i need to write for mapping in global.asax file ?

another question is that how could i pass my model or view model too when navigate from one view to another view.

looking for help & concept with sample code. thanks

Comment: Are register and home 2 different controllers. Why do you have 2 folders for actions in same controller? Please post your controller and view code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering your question, I've come up with the idea that your knowledge about web applications comes from ASP.NET that folders are used to categorize different area in a web application. If I were right, you should map folders in ASP.NET with Controllers In ASP.NET MVC (it is not good analogy, but for starting is helpful). In this way, you would have three Controllers or one Controller with three Actions. I am going to choose second one.

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
       var model = new TheViewModel(); 
       return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Catalog()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

View:

```
@model MvcApplication1.ViewModels.TheViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register")
<br/>
@Html.ActionLink("Catalog", "Catalog")
```

Your second question has answered at [Passing ViewModel in ASP.Net MVC from a View to a different View using Get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441567/passing-viewmodel-in-asp-net-mvc-from-a-view-to-a-different-view-using-get)

Answer (score 0):

Call the appropriate /controller/action in your respective button click handlers.

In your case for the register button handler direct it to `/home/register.`
Have a view for your register functionality.
In the register action of your home controller return the view you want to show.

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
return View();
}
```